# Pulling one member of a string and making it an int?

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to pull one member of a string and set that equal to an int. I understand that you can't simply put the int equal to the string value but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Here is the code snippet thats not working.

```
void zipcode::getZipCode(){
    int part[5];

    //This is what isn't correct.
    part[1] = strzip[1];

    cout << strzip[1] << " is equal to: " << part[1] << endl;

}
```

Can I use memcpy to copy the string member to an int value?

The string in question is: "
0010101001110000110011000"

and the output I'm getting now is:

0 is equal to: 48

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Atoi my friend, atoi ;) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) :V

Comment: @Puciek, No, please no. And why on bloody earth does that documentation not mention that failure to convert it returns 0?

Comment: `part[1] = strzip[1] - '0';`

Comment: cplusplus.com isn't a good reference. Also `atoi` or `stoi` both convert a **string** (`char *` or `std::string`), not a char.

Comment: Ok, I've been informed it does mention that, just not in the right section, and not visibly enough that I saw it reading through. Better than nothing. *rage detensifies*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in a string is castable to an int implicitly (a basic_string contains char type items which are mapped to ascii characters in standard in/out methods.)  Since each character is a number from 0 to 255 mapping to this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see how this plays out:

```
if('0' == 48){cout << "0 char is 48 int";}
```

C++ has several conversion methods.  With simple char types you can exploit the basic [ascii table layout](http://www.asciitable.com/) and treat it as a number:

```
int resultNumber = mystring[i] - '0';
```

Using the above method, you would be wise to check the character is in the range of '0' to '9' first.  The following does that check and returns -1 in the case of an error.

```
int resultNumber = (mystring[i] >= '0' && mystring[i] <= '9')?mystring[i] - '0':-1;
```

But you can also use [stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) because char will implicitly convert to a string.  This has the distinct benefit of working for more than a simple char.  There is minor overhead for casting a single character to a string vs the previous method, however.

```
int resultNumber = stoi(mystring[i]);
```

You can cast a whole string at once if you want (this will not work in your case because you **want** to check each character individually, but for a 2+ digit number it will work.)

C's [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) does the same thing but requires a char* (C style string) which will not implicitly work with a char type (casting to char* with &mystring[i] would also not work because it requires null termination).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response

Comment: @Pahjay Thank you.  I've included a few minor edits to further improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake. `Strings` are merely arrays of characters, and a (basic) character is a number between 1 and 127 (excluding some special control characters). "0" as a `char` is represented by the number 48, and hence "0" really equals 48, since "0" is a `char` and 48 is an `int`, and they are different ways of representing the same basic data.

Luckily for you, there's a fairly easy way to solve your problem: Just convert each `char` to its equivalent `int`:

```
cout << strzip[1] << " is equal to: " << strzip[1] - '0' << endl;
```

Please notice that you cannot use cstdlib's `atoi()` function here since it will convert your whole string to a number, and in your case that will cause the loss of your leading zeroes, and probably overflow your `int`.